# nuxt3 and vuetify3 Slow page response

Tags: nginx, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

I have created a front development environment using docker compose.
The configuration is nginx + nuxt3 + vuetify3.
I created vue in the Pages directory.
It took 120000ms to display it.
It's so slow that I can't even develop.

I'm trying to see why it's taking so long.
and it looks like it is getting all the vuetify code.

Also some of the requests are giving errors.

```
http://host.docker.internal/_nuxt/node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VChip/VChip.css
http://host.docker.internal/_nuxt/node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VGrid/VGrid.css
http://host.docker.internal/_nuxt/node_modules/nuxt/dist/pages/runtime/app.vue
http://host.docker.internal/_nuxt/node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VNoSsr/VNoSsr.mjs?v=afbc0ebb
http://host.docker.internal/_nuxt/node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VColorPicker/util/index.mjs?v=afbc0ebb
http://host.docker.internal/_nuxt/node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VList/VListChildren.mjs?v=afbc0ebb
http://host.docker.internal/_nuxt/node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VProgressCircular/VProgressCircular.css?v=afbc0ebb
```

The access is from host.docker.internal:80 leading to host machine:80 -> nginx container:80 -> nuxt container:3000.
The nuxt server is run by this command.

```
npx nuxi dev
```

I don't know why the above massive requests are taking place.
It also does not appear to be normal. What is wrong?

I am new to both nuxt and vuetify.
I am also not familiar with how webpack works.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue, maybe it would be wise to add your nuxt config.
Maybe someone can figure out what to do..

Mine is as followed:

```
{
...
  css: ['vuetify/styles'],
  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify'],
  },
  modules: [
    // eslint-disable-next-line require-await
    async (_options, nuxt) => {
      // @ts-ignore
      nuxt.hooks.hook('vite:extendConfig', (config) => config?.plugins && config.plugins.push(vuetify({ autoImport: true })))
    },
  ],
...
```

And plugins/vuetify.ts

```
// @ts-ignore
import {defineNuxtPlugin, useRuntimeConfig} from '#app'

import {createVuetify} from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import {aliases, mdi} from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi-svg'
import { md3 } from 'vuetify/blueprints'
import {useDark} from '@vueuse/core'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const isDark = useDark().value

  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    ssr: true,
    // https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/blueprints/
    blueprint: md3,
    components,
    icons: {
      defaultSet: 'mdi',
      aliases,
      sets: {
        mdi,
      },
    },
    // https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/
    theme: {
      defaultTheme: isDark ? 'dark' : 'light',
      themes: {
        dark, // theme defined earlier
        light, // theme defined earlier
      },
    },
  })
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```